# Create table fail in mysql when using CURDATE() as default

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create the following table using phpmyadmin sql console:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
(
id int NOT NULL,
id_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

However I get the following error:
[image]

It shows "CURDATE()" in red, so I guess that's the problem.

Could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Is `id_date` supposed to be a `date` or a `datetime`? The way you have named it and are using it is more like a `date`, but it is declared as a `datetime`.

Comment: I think if it was a datetime the correct function would be NOW() right ? still I think it won't work with NOW() and keeping DATETIME

Comment: NOW() also won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use CURDATE() as a default value.

Instead you can use a TIMESTAMP column with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Then you will have to ignore the time part of it.

Example SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    id_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO dates (id) VALUES (1);
SELECT id, DATE(id_date) AS id_date FROM dates;
```

Result:

```
id  id_date
1   2010-09-12
```

Comment: Could you show me some SQL code as an example ? I would really appreciate since my SQL experience is quite limited.

Comment: I know this is late but, yes the w3schools.com reference is INCORRECT. I personally have tried many times and confirm it to be false. Also from the MySQL documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html:
The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: was trying something similar, the following works.. strange .. i think its a product bug 

CREATE TABLE employee ( hire_date      timestamp         NOT NULL DEFAULT now() );