# MYSQL CURDATE() Not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Trans (
    tranID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tranDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURDATE(),
    amount INT,
    account_number INT,
        FOREIGN KEY(account_number) REFERENCES Account(account_number) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(tranID)

);
```

and every time a trans happens the date is inserted so it has a timestamp. However, I am getting an issue when trying to implement it. I got the CURDATE example off the W3C schools website to make my life easier but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing the `DEFAULT` keyword?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I had that in originally but took it out to see if it would change anything. I have put it back in now. THank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create table fail in mysql when using CURDATE() as default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696778/create-table-fail-in-mysql-when-using-curdate-as-default)

Comment: try using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`temp` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```