# MySQL error when trying to add new columns

Tags: mysql

Trying to insert new columns into my blog posts table as part of my sites update.

Here is the mysql code I am using:

```
ALTER TABLE blogposts
  ADD (
    postType varchar(20),
    postDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
    postTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURTIME()
  );
```

It throws this error though when executed:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURDATE(),
      postTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURTIME()
  )' at line 4
```

I assume that curdate() is the issue, but do not understand why since it is a valid mysql function.

**This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696778/create-table-fail-in-mysql-when-using-curdate-as-default) as was proposed.**, the solution in that post did not fix my problem and instead threw this error:

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'postDate'
```

When using code:

```
ALTER TABLE blogposts
  ADD (
    postType varchar(20),
    postDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    postTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURTIME()
  );
```

So for reference, this is not a duplicate question it seems.

Comment: You can't use `CURTIME()` either. Why do you need two columns, one for date and one for time, when you can cover both using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Because I want them separated out by default for easier calling from the backend. There must be a way to do this because these are valid mysql functions and even the w3c say it should work in this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp) and this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curtime.asp).

Comment: So, what I want to know is why isn't this working when these functions are valid and how can this be made to work.

Comment: In the way I expect it to work that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values for `DATETIME` columns are not available before MySQL Server 5.6.5.

In 5.6.5 and later, the value you specify as default must be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or an equivalent expression returning a *datetime* value.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> Because I want them separated out by default for easier calling from the backend.

That seems like a little bit of a frivolous motivation, when you can `SELECT TIME(c1) AS teh_time, DATE(c1) AS teh_date` if needed, and almost any other operation you wanted to do, like datetime math, time zone conversions or `DATE_FORMAT()` would require them to be recombined.

Comment: nice laid out answer