# mysql throwing syntax error for curdate() function

Tags: mysql

i am trying to create a sample table like this:

create table dummy (bb varchar(10),gg datetime DEFAULT CURDATE());

am i not supposed to use curdate function while table creation??

Comment: If you want date and time use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table fail in mysql when using CURDATE() as default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696778/create-table-fail-in-mysql-when-using-curdate-as-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use CURDATE() as a default value. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy
(
    bb varchar(10),gg TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: atleast can i use it while passing queries??

Comment: @pradyu:- Yes you can!