# How to set default value of MySQL DateTime ( not TIMESTAMP ) to NOW() or Current_DateTIme?

Tags: mysql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

I have a table with column CreatedDate of data type datetime and i want to be able to set its default value to current DateTime how do i do it?

I tried Now() and CurrentTimestamp but no luck so far!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only set a static default in the table definition.
So unless you want to call `ALTER TABLE` every minute....

Use a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bu_table1_each BEFORE UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.datefield = NOW();
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do it with DateTime.

See: [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)