# TIMESTAMP to DATETIME transition?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How can I convert a column with TIMESTAMP to DATETIME and retain the dates? I'm using PHPMyAdmin.

Also timestamp had the option to autofill, is there a way to do so in DATETIME? Or should I insert it each time with PHP?

thanks

Comment: TIMESTAMP the column-type, or TIMESTAMP the unix-timestamp?

Comment: Be aware that TIMESTAMP (MySQ: datatype) is stored in GMT and converted to current session timezone for presentation. DATETIME is stored as-is, so converting from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME in timezone other than GMT may result in times being offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this query

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE `time` `time` datetime
```

will lose dates you can create new column then assign old values then delete old column and rename new one

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD `datetime` datetime AFTER `time`;
UPDATE table set datetime=time;
ALTER TABLE table DROP datetime;
ALTER TABLE CHANGE `datetime` `time` datetime
```

[Read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):
This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as **[NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)** or **[CURRENT_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnname DATETIME;
```

(test on a test table first...)

No way to set the default to the current time save for triggers:

```
  DELIMITER $
  CREATE TRIGGER tablename_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.columnname IS NULL THEN
      SET NEW.columnname = NOW();
    END IF;
    IF NEW.datum = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
      SET NEW.columnname = NOW();
    END IF;
  END$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert from a unix timestamp into a regular datetime value.

A unix timestamp has no native type in mysql - it's simply an integer. `timestamp` fields will auto-populate, but only the first one in any given table. More details on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column).

Comment: Hm, good point, `TIMESTAMP` the column-type, or `TIMESTAMP` the unix-timestamp...