# Doctrine 2.1 - error in DateTimeType

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to add user to my database through Doctrine 2.1 project and I'm getting that kind of error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:...\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php on line 44

Database table itself created with no problems. What could be wrong with my following code?

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=20, unique=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $login;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $nickname;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=24)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $birth_date;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", nullable=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @Column(type="boolean")
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $activation = FALSE;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=TRUE)
     */
    protected $registration_date;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=TRUE)
     */
    protected $login_date;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $forum_posts_amount = 0;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", length=3)
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $forum_group = 0;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $comments_amount = 0;

    /**
     * @Column(type="boolean")
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $newsletter = FALSE;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->registration_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    public function getLogin() { return $this->login; }
    public function setLogin($login) { $this->login = $login; }

    public function getNickname() { return $this->nickname; }
    public function setNickname($nickname) { $this->nickname = $nickname; }

    public function getFirstname() { return $this->firstname; }
    public function setFirstname($firstname) { $this->firstname = $firstname; }

    public function getLastname() { return $this->lastname; }
    public function setLastname($lastname) { $this->lastname = $lastname; }

    public function getEmail() { return $this->email; }
    public function setEmail($email) { $this->email = $email; }

    public function getPassword() { return $this->password; }
    public function setPassword($password) { $this->password = $password; }

    public function getCity() { return $this->city; }
    public function setCity($city) { $this->city = $city; }

    public function getBirthDate() { return $this->birth_date; }
    public function setBirthDate($birth_date) { $this->birth_date = $city; }

    public function getDescription() { return $this->description; }
    public function setDescription($description) { $this->description = $description; }

    public function setLoginDate($login_date) { $this->login_date = $login_date; }

    public function getForumGroup() { return $this->forum_group; }
    public function setForumGroup($forum_group) { $this->forum_group = $forum_group; }

    public function getCommentsAmount() { return $this->comments_amount; }
    public function boostCommentsAmount() { $this->comments_amount++; }

    public function getNewsletter() { return $this->newsletter; }
    public function setNewsletter($newsletter) { $this->newsletter = $newsletter; }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2.1 - datetime column default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698625/doctrine-2-1-datetime-column-default-value)

Comment: You also have an error in `setBirthDate()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doctrine requires `date(time)` columns to contain `DateTime`objects. So in fact your constructor should read

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->registration_date = new \DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's something with the __construct()