# DATETIME Default value 0 MYSQL 5.5.25

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date

I'm trying to create these table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qa_discountcoupons` (
  `discount_code` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `status_code` INT NOT NULL ,
  `discount_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discount_code`) ,
  INDEX `discounts_to_status` (`status_code` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `discounts_to_status`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_code` )
    REFERENCES `qa_status` (`status_code` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

But i get this error:

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'discount_date'
```

Comment: See similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qa_discountcoupons` (
 `discount_code` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `status_code` INT NOT NULL ,
 `discount_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`discount_code`) ,
 INDEX `discounts_to_status` (`status_code` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `discounts_to_status`
 FOREIGN KEY (`status_code` )
 REFERENCES `qa_status` (`status_code` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

from MySQL 5.6.5 and up.

I suggest also checking out the thread on [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column) - which has a lot of comments on this.

Comment: there any way to set it to 0?

Comment: Well - 0 is not really a date - but you could choose some arbitary date and use that as your "null point" - like January 1st 1970 or something.
A good design would use NULL for 0 though.

Comment: If your SQL Mode does not inclue `NO_ZERO_DATE` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date), you *could* do `discount_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'` but as advised by Kerbocat, `NULL` is definitely preferable.