# Mysql default value for Date and Datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, phpmyadmin

Can any one specify, how can be set default value for Date and Datetime field in Mysql from phpmyadmin interface?

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin? Also, [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com) is a better fit for this question.

Comment: You can check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` constant

also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Comment: Thank you. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is only for 'timestamp' type, not for 'date' & 'datetime' type.

Comment: @SumeshTG: FYI - storing date and time, as it is in database not suggestible.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify exact default values for DATE and DATETIME fields, e.g. -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  date_column DATE DEFAULT '2012-01-01',
  datetime_column DATETIME DEFAULT '2010-05-05 10:30:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (1);

SELECT * FROM table1;

+----+-------------+---------------------+
| id | date_column | datetime_column     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2012-01-01  | 2010-05-05 10:30:00 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

If you want to use function to define DEFAULT values, then you can create a trigger.

Comment: Thank you. Can you specify how to set default 'date' as 'current date' and 'datetime' as 'current date time', without using a trigger?.

Comment: No, there is no good ways. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't allow using functions to set default values for DATE, DATETIME fields. You also may implement this logic in a stored procedure, and use it to add new records.