# MySQL default datetime through phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In an existing database, I've age column (INT). Now I need to set it as dob (DATETIME).

I try doing so through PHPMyAdmin, giving CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value as defined by [answer with 138 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column). However PHPMyAdmin is complaining `#1067 - invalid default value for 'dob'` as in attached screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Can someone please suggest why I'm getting that error and how to fix that?

Comment: Wondering how date of birth can have current time as default value?

Comment: [DATETIME Vs TIMESTAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

Comment: @Mithun. Just temporary value. later will change with other values.

Comment: works that way now

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[You can't set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value with DATETIME.

But you can do it with TIMESTAMP.

See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp).

Words from [this](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/is-it-possible-to-set-current-datetime-as-default-value-in-date-column-in-mysql/) blog

The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.

The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

Comment: Thanks. I used null as temporary value. Initially I was trying to go through `not null` and using current date as default value but seems it is not possible. Allowed null temporarily and it worked.

Comment: For future readers: note that this is no longer true. `DATETIME` can have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value since MySQL 5.6.5.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 4):

Set the type of the field as TIMESTAMP too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can achieve that with mysql date. You have to use timestamp or try this approach..

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_OnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON `DB`.`table`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dateColumn = IFNULL(NEW.dateColumn, NOW());
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because the default value `current_time` is not valid for the type `DATETIME`. That's what it says, and that's whats going on.

The only field you can use `current_time` on is a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for DateTime is use a Trigger:

```
/************ ROLE ************/
drop table if exists `role`;
create table `role` (
    `id_role` bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `date_created` datetime,
    `date_deleted` datetime,
    `name` varchar(35) not null,
    `description` text,
    primary key (`id_role`)
) comment='';

drop trigger if exists `role_date_created`;
create trigger `role_date_created` before insert
    on `role`
    for each row 
    set new.`date_created` = now();
```