# In phpMyAdmin creating of a new column in _users structure leads to an error #1067

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

If I insert anything new column it shows the error #1067. If I delete last six column then I can add but again can't enter the 6 column back.

[image]

Comment: check registerDate coloumn

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063980/mysql-default-datetime-through-phpmyadmin) for reference.

Comment: You don't need to specify the length for datatype `TEXT`.

Comment: thank you guys you make my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table registerDate column you have to remove default value. because its not correct format for the given type

Comment: Thanks, I change default to current_timestamp now it's working