# Add a date field in php my admin

Tags: mysql

I have tried to add a date filed in phpMyAdmin

## 1067 - Invalid default value for 'AddDate'

It wants Length/Values, Collation, Attributes.

Are these necessary? Does the database not know the length of a DATE field?

HELP PLEASE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL default datetime through phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063980/mysql-default-datetime-through-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in Mysql "Date" datatype cannot set default date, you may need to change your datatype to DateTime or Timestamp using which we can store the default date.

Please refer the Question asked and its accpeted answer

Visit: [How to set default value of DATE (not DATETIME/TIMESTAMP) column to current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805705/how-to-set-default-value-of-date-not-datetime-timestamp-column-to-current-date)