# Column that will dysplay current date in grocery_crud CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

In grocery_crud and Code Igniter in table Employees I have column today(dd/mm/yyyy). How to set column to display current date. Please help me.

Comment: would strtotime() work? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can't do this with a Date but with a Timestamp column, and you add 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as the default value.

That said as of MySQL version 5.6.5 you can do it with :

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `creation_time`     DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `modification_time` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

as explained here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603198/1226118