# to store datetime automatically using Yii

Tags: php, datetime, yii

I am starting to learn php using Yii, and I have a big question, maybe you can help me.

I am using a form to create users. I want to store the data of the users that I introduce in the form into the DB (MySQL), but I also must store the date and the time in the datetime field of the DB. I saw some extensions like CJUIDATEPICKER to pick the date, but I don't know any extension to pick the datetime. I think that the better way is to store the datetime automatically when I create a new user. Now I have a textbox in the form where I have to introduce the datetime with the format yyyy-mmmm-dddd hh:mm:ss, but I think that it isn't useful.

Please, someone coud help me and explain to me how to store a datetime when I create a register into the DB?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Now I use "$model->reg_date=new CDbExpression('NOW()');" inside the actionCreate() controller and it works well but I think that would be better to show this datetime inside the field of the user creation form before you write anything and to store all the fields of the form when you click on submit. I tried to do it but as you can imagine the field only show "NOW()"

This is part of my code of the form in _form.php:

```
<div class="row">
<?php $model->reg_date=new CDbExpression('NOW()');?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'reg_date'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'reg_date'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'reg_date'); ?>
</div>
```

Someone could help me?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose to store the datetime automatically when you create a new user, I'd use [CDbExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression):

```
$model->created = new CDbExpression('NOW()'); // "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```

And UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) for a unix timestamp. It should be worth mentioning that those functions are MySQL-specific.

I'd also like to point out that [CJuiDatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker/) is a *widget* that comes bundled with Yii. Sorry for the nitpicking.

---

Updated answer using php's date function instead of MySQL's NOW():

```
// UserController.php
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;
    $model->created = date("Y-m-d H:i");  // Added this.
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

// _form.php  inside your Active Form
echo $form->labelEx($model,'created');   // Display it anyway you'd like. A label perhaps?
echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'created'); // Send back value to the controller on submit
```

That should be it!

And something worth mentioning if you use bootstrap. Don't place a hidden field first in a form because bootstraps first-child css-selectors will mess up the top margin.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote CDbExpression('NOW()'); into the controller actionCreate() but I think that will be better to show this datetime in the field of the user creation form before to write anything in it and to store this datatime field when you click in sumit. Could you help me?

Comment: Alright, I have updated the answer. I haven't tried it mind you, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks ippi, your solution is very useful, now I only have a small question. How I could to set the hour of a country where the person create the register? I mean, I want that the hour depends of the country.

Answer (score 2):

**No Need to Add date time feild in your form**
**Just remove the date time feild from your Form**.

**And Add CDbExpression('NOW()') to your Model in rules, Just see Example**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
//date_modified and date_created is my database field names..
               array('date_modified','default',
                    'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),//automatically add the current date in mysql feild
                     'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
                   array('date_created,date_modified','default',
                'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert'),
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in user or registration controller just write inside actionCreate() method..

```
public function actionCreate()
{
       if(isset($_POST['user']
       {
             $model->attributes=$_POST['user'];
             $model->created_date=new CDbExpression('NOW()'); //inserting created time

             // ...
       }
}
```

it will automatically insert your user created time.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, it works well but, it would be possible to show this datetime automatically in the form before you write anything? I mean, don't create the register datetime into the controller actionCreate, but to show the datatime filed full in the form and to store it when you click sumit.

Answer (score 0):

If the `datetime` field is to be set automatically you could change it to a `timestamp` instead and set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its default as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168832/428543).

If you insist on using `datetime`, you could use a trigger as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483959/428543).

Comment: thanks topher, but I prefer to use $model->reg_date=new CDbExpression('NOW()') since this is easier hehe. Besides I must use datetime.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to modify your view try the -> [kartiks TimePicker widget](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker)

ex:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'time')->widget(TimePicker::classname(),[
'pluginOptions' => ['defaultTime' => 'current'] ]);?>
```