# Default of datetime in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I set default of datetime in mariadb 5.5 such as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    `create_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But it displays this error

```
Error 1067: Invalid default value for 'create_time'
```

How can I set default current time value in mariadb but don't use TIMESTAMP type ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: no, my question is about mariadb not mysql

Comment: and since mariadb is a drop-in replacement for mysql the answer probably applies...?

Comment: because can set default current_timestamp in mysql but can't in mariadb so that I ask this question

Comment: mariadb 5.5 is based on mysql 5.5 where this didn't work either. mysql only supports this from 5.6.5 onwards according to that answer

Comment: in MariaDB 10.0 this works

Comment: but it's alpha version

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to use MariaDB 10 to get this functionality. It's frustrating, I know, but it still hasn't  been (may never be?) "backported" to MariaDB 5.5.

Comment: MariaDB 10.0 released: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.0/

Answer (score 3):

In 5.5 you cannot use [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/current_timestamp/) as the default value for a [`DATETIME`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datetime/) column. This was later introduced in 10.0.1 to make its use possible.

Your options are to either upgrade to a newer version or to emulate it using a trigger ([as was explained by *inanutshellus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960049/7633996)).

Answer (score 1):

Specify it using a trigger:

```
create trigger bi_mytable
before insert on mytable 
for each row 
begin
    NEW.create_time = NOW();
end;
```

And, since it's a "create" value, make sure nobody updates it:

```
create trigger bu_mytable
before update on mytable 
for each row 
begin
    NEW.create_time = OLD.create_time;
end;
```