# I can't modify a table's column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to update a column in a table, as the following :

```
ALTER TABLE annonce MODIFY COLUMN date_crea DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

but I got this error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Perhaps show your structure of your table.. my guess is there date_crea or something like that is spelled wrong.

Comment: You're missing the datatype. `ALTER TABLE annonce MODIFY COLUMN date_crea TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` or `datetime` [dependant on version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/168832/73226)