# Error with Persistent syntax using MySQL and Yesod

Tags: mysql, haskell, yesod, persistent

I am currently building a website using Haskell and the Yesod platform, and a MySQL database. I would like to make use of the Persistent module within Yesod. To do so, I have followed the [guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) on this module. Everything worked, until I wanted to add a default value to the `accountCreatedDate` column in my database. Here is my models file:

```
User
    idAccount AccountId Int
    userLastName Text Maybe
    userFirstName Text Maybe
    userAge Int Maybe
    userSex Text Maybe
    userEMail Text
    UniqueUserEMail userEMail
Account
    accountName Text
    accountPassword Text
    accountCreatedDate UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    accountLastLogin UTCTime
    UniqueAccountName accountName
```

When I run yesod devel, I get the following error:

> devel.hs: ConnectionError {errFunction = "query", errNumber = 1064, errMessage = "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIME' at line 1"}
>   Exit code: ExitFailure 1

What I find weird about this error, is that I have copied the guide for that exact line (except the name of the column). What do I have to change in order to fix this problem?

EDIT: I have also tried `CURRENT_TIME()`.

EDIT2: My current MySQL version is 5.5 and this is the query Yesod is trying to do:

```
CREATe TABLE `account`(`id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`account_name` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,`account_password` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,`account_created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,`account_last_login` DATETIME NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Use `printMigration` to see the query it is producing, and then debug it further. Most probably the query Yesod is generating is not compatible with Mysql version.

Comment: @Sibi I have added the query Yesod is trying to do, and my MySQL version as well, in my question.

Comment: Try running that query directly in your mysql prompt and see if that works. If it doesn't work, then most probably it is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, it seems that it is not possible to set a default value using a function like CURRENT_TIME with my version of MySQL for a DateTime column. Since UTCTime in Yesod/Persistent is a DateTime, I guess I cannot do this. It seems however that his is possible with MySQL 5.6.5.

I have found the information on the following link: [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)