# mysql insert current date, only in insert time

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the table structure,

```
id             int
name           varchar
insert_date    date
update_date    TIMESTAMP
```

Now here the idia is , **insert_date** will be able to insert by defult current time & the update_date it will insert current time in each edit or insert it will update it.

so how i could make the (insert_date) default value to current time and date but on update it should not change the value of (insert_date) if i keep it TIMESTAMP on update it will change.

insert_date -- insert current time , only in insert just one time

regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may use `NOW()` function in you respective fields

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add only time .. you need to use

CURTIME()

AND if you want current date and time...

NOW()

If you want only current date....

CURDATE()

for more here..

The following SELECT statement:
SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()

will result in something like this:
NOW()   CURDATE()   CURTIME()
2008-11-11 12:45:34     2008-11-11  12:45:34

Choose format as you want.

Answer (score 2):

use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for insert

use  `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for update

like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datetest` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `timestamps_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `timestamps_inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

Comment: I get this error #1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamps_updated'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep default current date & time means, you want to change

```
insert_date data type date to datetime
```

And insert like

```
Insert into tbl(insert_date) values(now())
```

or

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Insert into tbl(insert_date) values('$date')
```

or

Read it

[How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATETIME` type if you want to store **Date and time**, and you can choose `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value or use `NOW()` to get current date and time (yyyy-mm-dd Hour:minutes:seconds).