# Column name is not taking timestamp as default value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1067

I have two columns **created_at** and **updated_at** in same table. Both the columns have data type as **datetime**. Now when I am trying to modify the column data types as follows -

```
alter table nodestatics modify column updated_at datetime default current_timestamp; 

alter table nodestatics modify column created_at datetime default current_timestamp;
```

It is showing the following error

> Error Code : 1067 Invalid default value for 'updated_at' (0 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at' (0 ms taken)

My mysql version is 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to reference [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) in a comment:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for `TIMESTAMP`, and
>   for at most one `TIMESTAMP` column per table.

Either upgrade to 5.6.5.  Or use `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.

Comment: One more query though. Can we use now() to overcome this ? If yes then how can it be possible ?

Comment: @AnirudhRautela . . . No.  You can use a trigger to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`

---

Should be something like this:

`ALTER TABLE nodestatics MODIFY COLUMN updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

`ALTER TABLE nodestatics MODIFY COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

---

Or you can use `TRIGGERS`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTable_OnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON `tblMyTable`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dateAdded = NOW();
```

You can look at [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column). Happy coding!

Comment: We can use TIMESTAMP for just one column in a particular table.

Comment: In this case you can use `Triggers`. Check my given link how to use It.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alter table nodestatics modify column created_at timestamp default current_timestamp;
```