# error in your SQL syntax; to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' created_at DATETIME NOT NULL' at line 2

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to created `created_at` column but I am always getting the following error.

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' created_at DATETIME NOT NULL' at line 2

What am I doing wrong? I tested the query without created_at and it works the table I created.

I appreciate any help.

```
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES LIKE'" . $route ."'"  ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
  echo "Table exist";
} else {
  $res = $con->query ( "CREATE TABLE " . $route . "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL), created_at DATETIME NOT NULL" ) or die($con->error);

  echo "table was craeted";
}
```

Comment: Remove the `)` before `, created_at` ...

Comment: I removed it and I am getting `corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`

Comment: add it back in, AFTER `created_at DATETIME NOT NULL`

Comment: I've posted an answer below should you not have seen it. @benz

Comment: [you see, explaining where your code fails, helps to teach you in where your mistakes were made.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29900499/1415724). - I don't say "try" in my answers, but pointed out "where" you've gone wrong ;-) I'll bet you didn't bother looking at mine neither. Next time, I'll just let it slide.

Comment: make up your mind when you choose an answer. You selected mine after then back to the other one. I even told the guy in comments if they tested it before posting; it's a thankless job lol! it's expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way after removing extra `)` after your `longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL` column. That extra `)` causes you `SQL` syntax error.

```
if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
    echo "Table exist";
 }else{
    $res = $con->query ( "CREATE TABLE $route
    (
     id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at DATETIME NOT NULL)" 
    ) or die($con->error);
  echo "table was craeted";
}
```

Comment: did you put that into an IDE before posting? there's a bracket missing.

Comment: *"Try this way after removing extra ) after your longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL"* - all brackets are accounted for, the 2 added brackets either don't belong, or are misplaced.

Comment: @Being: I tired your syntax and I am getting `corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5` I have already deleted  'the double hat' but I am still getting the error at line 5?

Comment: @benz you can set like this `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced bracket following `NULL` in `longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL)` <=

```
 $res = $con->query ( "CREATE TABLE " . $route . "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL), created_at DATETIME NOT NULL" ) or die($con->error);
                                                                     ^ right there.
```

Which belongs after `NULL` in `created_at DATETIME NOT NULL`

```
$res = $con->query ( "CREATE TABLE " . $route . " (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL)") or die($con->error);
```

---

- My successful test constituted in using `$route = "table_test_xxx";`