# Adding a new column with the current time as a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, ddl

I am looking for the syntax to add a column to a MySQL table with the current time as a default value.

Comment: Read the [mysql doumatation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)  about alter table syntax

Comment: I love that someone upvoted this. Hooray for democracy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** It is now possible to achieve this with `DATETIME` fields since **MySQL 5.6.5**, take a look at the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603198/4275342) below...

It is now possible to achieve this with `DATETIME` fields since MySQL 5.6.5
But you can do it with `TIMESTAMP`:

```
 create table test (str varchar(32), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I am looking for the syntax to add just the time (HH:MM:SS)

Comment: What is type of your column?

Comment: I can change it, it is not a problem, I can fit it  to the type of the return value function

Comment: The function CURTIME() doesn't work, it indicat  a syntax error

Comment: "MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format." This is from mysql site. You can store only this type, but you can use one of the many time format functions to change it, when you need to display it. For excample: `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(ts, '%T') FROM test`

Answer (score 14):

Even so many persons have provided solution but this is just to add more information-

If you just want to insert current timestamp at the time of row insertion-

```sql
    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mytimestampcol TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If you also want that this column should update if any update this row then use this-

```sql
    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mytimestampcol TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Zafar Malik, I m looking for only the time format "HH:MM:SS"

Comment: Even there is time datatype in mysql but it is not with auto fill property, buty yes you can keep column property timestamp for auto fill and then select only time from that.

Comment: How can I select just time ?, the sql syntax please.

Comment: select time(timestampcol) from mytable;

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a `default` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN (mytimestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will useful to you.

```
create table test (column_name varchar(32), time_column TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

mysql> insert into test (column_name) values ("demo");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select column_name as name, time_column as ts from  test;
+------+---------------------+
| name | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
| demo | 2014-07-31 15:42:52 | 
+------+---------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test (col1 varchar(10), lastaccessdate TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6));
```

this will update time with fractional seconds in time, and also update when record is last inserted or updated.