# Automated date column in MySQL when row is added

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

At the time a customer places an order on my website, how can I make it so the "order_date" column is automatically populated with the date the data is added to the database?

Is this something I have to include in my update statement or can I somehow make the database automatically add a date to when the row was inserted?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this MySQL query to make [default value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) as [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for the required field:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `orderDate` `orderDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This is if you're running MySQL <5.6.5. Above, you can have your field to be of `DATETIME` and therefore run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `orderDate` `orderDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: I am running "ALTER TABLE `orders` CHANGE `OrderDate` `OrderDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and get this error #1067 - Invalid default value for 'OrderDate'.

Comment: What is the type of your `orderDate` field? [It must by of `TIMESTAMP` if you're running MySQL <5.6.5, it can be `DATETIME` above this version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/168832/2788131).

Comment: The OrderDate field type is DATETIME. The length/value is 50.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: ##MySQL client version: 5.1.73.

Comment: Therefore, your field must be of `TIMESTAMP` type. I have edited my answer according to your needs.

Comment: Spot on.

Thank you very much David!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the database automatically add a date to your datetime column when the row was inserted using now() function of php.

```
 <?php  
$query="insert into tableName (other_columns, date_column) values ('$valueForOtherColumn', now())";
?>
```