# TimeStamp column always gets zero value

Tags: mysql

I have the following query to set a default value to a column:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN testDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But I see `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for testDate column in newly inserted rows.

I would like to see current date and time in it.

Can anybody explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Can u try to check NOW() instead should be able to accomplish you challenge?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column) also, this only sets the value of new rows if it is not specified in the *insert query*.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable That's the query that I posted and it is not working

Comment: Can we see your *insert query*?

Comment: @CreativeCreator I have tried now() as well.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable You are seeing the query in the question, so there are 10 records in the table already and since I am creating new column in the table I want the default value to be current time

Comment: Can we get to see the **insert** query? The query that is used to add rows (collection of collums) to the table(collection of rows)?

Comment: @john.p.doe, why my answer doesn't satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data, you specified in your `INSERT` query, override default values of column, i.e. **default values works if no data set for column**.

See my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16aa4/1).

Comment: You should exclude testDate in your INSERT statement, because default value works if no data is set for column

Comment: its the name of the new column

Comment: Data, you specified in your INSERT query, override default values of column, i.e. default values works if no data set for column.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get you, could you please edit your answer with a working query

Comment: @john.p.doe, you need only to exclude testDate from your INSERT query, or set testDate = NOW(). Both works.

Answer (score 0):

Default values only work if the value is not defined in the query.

This will use the default value for test:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(userid, email) VALUES(42, 'info@example.org');
```

While this will override the default value of test:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(userid,email,test/*here is when it goes wrong, you shouldn't mention the column in your insert statement at all*/) VALUES(42,'bush@example.did','2001-09-11 00:00:00');
```