# Set Date column to current time in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set the date column to the current time stamp but for some reason I keep getting a syntax error.

```
$sql = "UPDATE testGraph
    SET date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    SET State = ".$state1."
    WHERE Serial = ".$serial1."
   ";
```

Comment: possible duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: @rodrigo its a command not a string

Comment: You're just forgetting a comma between more then (1) `SET column = value`

Answer (score 1):

Only one `SET` keyword is allowed in an UPDATE statement.

Replace the second `SET` keyword with a comma.

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET mycol1  = expr1
     , mycol2  = expr2
--   ^
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help spencer

Answer (score 0):

In a update query only one SET attribute is used 
Syntax

`UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;`