# Default Date Value in MySQL create table not working

Tags: mysql, sql, date, default-value, create-table

I have the following create table statement (in MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE bugs (id INT, open_date DATE, 
close_date DATE DEFAULT STR_TO_DATE('9999-99-99', '%Y-%m-%d'), severity INT);
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and returns an error because of the default date value. Any other way to set a particular default value to date when using the create table statement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE bugs (id INT, open_date DATE, 
close_date DATE DEFAULT '9999-99-99', severity INT);
```

for more information, use the below link:-

[How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Comment: Not working. returns: CREATE TABLE bugs (id INT, open_date DATE,  close_date DATE DEFAULT '9999-99-99', severity INT) Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'close_date'

Comment: oh sorry
Please use '9999-9-9' instead of '9999-99-99'

Comment: Because 99 is not valid date or month, you can use till 31  for date and 12 for month

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's default DATE field format is YYYY-MM-DD. The supported range is 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31.
But you can't insert only date there,You need timestamp here

```
CREATE TABLE bugs
      (id INT, open_date DATE, 
       close_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '2016-11-30 22:30:00',
       severity INT
      );
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75d3e)

Since MySQL 5.6 DATE should work with default value NOW()

For more on Mysql dates [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)