# MYSQL query to alter timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql

MYSQL VERSION - 5.7.14

In mysql version I am not able to insert timestamp value with `null` in insert query.

I tried to alter the timestamp coulmn in mysql with the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `modified` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

But I am getting the error
`#1067 - Invalid default value for 'modified'`

Comment: remove `NOT NULL` from the end of each line you want to set null

Comment: If you try `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' ` ?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012579/1363190

Comment: I run the first query removing the `not null`. still getting the same error.

Comment: @MichaelK - That doesn't work as well.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE business MODIFY created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` either?

Comment: @MichaelK - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should not be in quotes. Even so keeping the quotes or removing the quotes. the query suggested generates error in sql syntax

Comment: Does this give an error to? `ALTER TABLE business MODIFY created TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` (If you want to allow null, else remove the  `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// TO ALLOW NULL AND SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DEFAULT:
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
// TO ALLOW NULL AND SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DEFAULT AND ON UPDATE:  
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If you do not want to allow null then just remove the `NULL`:

```
// DO NOT ALLOW NULL, SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DEFAULT:
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
// DO NOT ALLOW NULL, SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DEFAULT AND ON UPDATE:  
ALTER TABLE `business` MODIFY `modified` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```