# Add default value for date column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add an default value for my date column. The default value should be `GETDATE()`. I want to do this so I can see the date of the created row. When I try to save it I get the warning: `Incorrect default value for date`.

Does someone know why I am getting the warning and how I can fix it?

Comment: It looks like the possibilities for default values in MySQL are rather restricted compared to what's allowed in a normal insert/update, but does this work? (It's for another type, wondering if it works for date too) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603198

Comment: Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of getdate()

Comment: GETDATE() isnt a mysql function NOW() is

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is giving the same error

Comment: `NOW()` is also

Comment: How are you setting it? via an alter table statement show your code

Comment: No. I am trying to set it in phpmyadmin

Comment: did you use **smalldatetime** or **date** datatype??

Comment: Its just date (year-month-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query

```
ALTER TABLE `YourDb.yourtable`
    CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The Change column is oldval newval and the type
make sure if your column name isnt date to change it appropriately

additionally if you want that timestamp to update when the row is modified use

```
CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: This method is working. But it is also adding the time. I just want to add date (year-month-day). How can I change it to (year-month-day)

Comment: mysql only alows default timestamps for for the timestamp and datetime date types.

you can remove the time portion in select query by using the date() function 
e.g. SELECT DATE(date)
FROM `YourDb.yourtable`