# I need to set a column as the current date on table creation MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create a table that includes a column that contains just the current date-not timestamp-using the MariaDB base. Which is the command that sets the content of the column as the current date upon table creation?

Comment: It depends on what version you are running!

Comment: Since this question is specifically about MariaDB, I am reopening.  The alleged [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column) was specific to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Why on table create, as there will be no data, if you need a date and not datetime add to code, WELL before adding a trigger, keep business logic at the business layer not at storage layer.

Not your exact answer to the specific question but hopefully helpful advice, btw I don’t like triggers, so am a bit biased

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB introduced `DEFAULTs` for `DATETIME` in 10.0.1.

See [worklog](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-452) .  It is patterned after the [MySQL 5.6.5 feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) , which has examples.

If you want to default to only `CURDATE()`, I think you are out of luck in MariaDB and MySQL.

A `BEFORE INSERT` `TRIGGER` with `SET NEW.datetime_col = CURDATE()` should give you the functionality:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_date  BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.datetime_col = CURDATE();
```