# ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'date_time' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new and was trying to upload a sql dump file which was working perfectly on my local machine, into a cloud 9. But on importing the file i am getting this error

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'date_time'

The sql command in the dump file thats giving this error is

```
--
-- Table structure for table `history`
--

CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `shares` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(65,4) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(65,4) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;                    

--
-- Dumping data for table `history`
--
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: that helped thanks, I needed to update my mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update. Instead, change it to a TIMESTAMP.