# Store Default date as Today's date column in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there any configuration option available in Appmaker to Store Today's date as Default in a column record in Appmaker data source?

The current configuration directly provided an option to select date only, no option to write a script which can return me Today's date.
[image: Current option for choosing date]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, App Maker doesn't provide such setting at this time, but there are at least two ways how you can do it:

1. If you you are using [Custom Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql) instance you can make your table look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column/10603198#10603198):

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `creation_time`     DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `modification_time` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

2. In case you don't have direct access to the database you can add the following code in `onBeforeCreate` [model event](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events)

```javascript
record.CreatedOn = new Date();
```