# trying to get current datetime inserted into db but producing an error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have a column with the datatype DATETIME and im trying to get it to automatically insert the current date and time. i tried setting the value to NOW() but it gave the following error

> ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'date' at row 1

does anyone know how this is accomplished? im using mysql workbench

Comment: It would probably be useful to see that actual statement you have written

Comment: set `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the table definition and it's fixed

Comment: Are you inserting `"NOW()"` with quotes? Maybe it's understood as a string where you really want NOW() as a function without the quotes.

Comment: Martin im using mysql workbench so im not writing the query. @lelio, i have already created the tables and its columns. i tried to alter the table via workbench and tried to set the column in question to "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" but it gave an error. also didnt give an error code it just says it contains errors and cannot be accepted

Comment: Please show up your original code so I can try to help up you.

Comment: im using mysqlworkbench like i said i dont have any original code im using a gui

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` should return the datetime correctly which should match the field type. As I mentioned in the comment, you might be inserting the value `"NOW()"` as a literal string, which isn't a valid datetime format. Make sure you don't have quotes around `NOW()`.

Comment: i didnt have quotes around NOW(). is the datatype i specified correct to use the now function?

Comment: @Cole-p in your question when you said "automatically", do you mean setting a default value? If this is what you mean, you can take a look here at this question because there's a slight dependency on the version you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: thanks, thats what lelio was saying but its not working for me. i have already created the table in mysql workbench so when i try to alter it using the gui it doesnt accept it. what would be the sql code to alter the column so i can try input it manually?

Comment: have this sorted now found the option in mysqlworkbench

Comment: @Cole-p make sure to remove the two paranthases `()` after `DATETIME` in Workbench like this: https://pasteboard.co/IqonETd.png