# MySQL MYISAM engine does not accept default timestamp value

Tags: php, mysql, time, myisam

I have MyISAM engine running in my cPanel server ,**the server does not support InnoDB Engine**, i only have MyISAM engine.
  When i try to create a table column of type timestamp with a default value of (current time + 5 minutes) it gives an error.
This worked in my machine with InnoDB but in the server with MyISAM it gives an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that... near DEFAULT (NOW() + 300)`

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
    token_death_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (NOW() + 300)
   );
```

I also tried

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
    token_death_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
   );
```

**Can I achieve what I want with MyISAM or I have to do the 'adding' in my PHP script?**

Comment: Considering that "on the server i don't have privileges to create triggers" I'd recommend you to take these 5 minutes into account in the query which checks the expiration of the token.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you can find solution using variable and prepare statement.

Comment: @Akina thanks but i have problems synchronizing the time of php and the mysql time.

Comment: *i have problems synchronizing the time of php and the mysql time.* Perform all calculations on the server side - and this problem will have no base for to occurr.

Answer (score 2):

you cant use function for default value (before version 8)

but you can use trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test 
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.token_death_time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

Comment: If InnoDB is locked then I'm afraid that triggers creation is locked too...

Comment: Yes it worked in machine but on the server i don't have privileges to create triggers, and i can't change them. i also tried creating a function and call it on default, can't create functions too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   token_death_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

To set desired timestamp as default, you can set it in variable and can use prepare & execute statement, use below code:

```
SET @def_timestamp = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SET @query = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE test(token_death_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '", @def_timestamp , "')");
PREPARE stmt from @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Does not match OP's task.

Comment: Your question was "MySQL MYISAM engine does not accept default timestamp value". So my answer is, it allow CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default to be set

Comment: Subject != question. Subject even have no question mark in it...

Comment: You are specifying your problem by subject. It means you specified wrong subject than. MyIsam allow CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to set as a default value, That's it

Comment: Please address your words to the question author.

Comment: @Akina, Than why are you getting into this if I'm answering something. Rather you should do your own business. And by the way according to subject, my answer is definitely correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/168832/7388520

Comment: I don't mind your answer being published. Moreover, the information in it corresponds to reality. However, the author does not just need CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but also plus five minutes - that is, not what is done in your answer. That's what I said.

Comment: @PradeepDarjee i can't write the whole question in the title!, i give a short description in the title and i specify in the description.the subject is about default time, i was correct

Comment: @ZOLDIK Yes, It's okay

Comment: considering your edit `SET @def_timestamp = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);` will set @def_timestamp to a fixed time (the time when the variable was created + interval ), i don't want that i want it to be ( the time where i add the new record + interval ), you can see that time with `select @def_timestamp`

Answer (score -1):

The DEFAULT value expression which you need is available for MySQL version 8.0.13 or later ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1c6ea235b71c6e0135cad292648c0de) - both queries are successfully executed on 8.0.19 version).

See [Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).

And the issue is not relative to the table's engine.